# String match/substring/replace/split JavaScript ,

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

for simplicity, I have a text which has the following format

```
"[{\"title\":\"Campus (Pinte)\",\"quantity\":2}]"
```

now ,here I will add a challenge,
what's in between "title\":\" and \",\"quantity\ can be change

I show you one

```
"[{\"title\":\"Bellerose (Pinte)\",\"quantity\":4}]"
```

we can show the have be change 
especially the word length

so now what am I trying to do 
I would like to stop displaying, for example the " title" and the "()" the "\"

this is what i have already tried

```
{console.log(datass.items.substring(11)}
{console.log(datass.items.match(/title/g))}
{console.log(datass.items.replace("title", "1"))}
{console.log(datass.items.split("(,)}{]:"))}
```

Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Neff

Comment: Looks like valid JSON, why not to parse it to a live array, and use that array to show the content.

Comment: @Teemu 
excellent question, can you tell me a little more? or do you have an example?

Comment: See how to parse it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1hfnybc/). If you want to remove parts of the title text, it would be much easier when having a live object instead of a string.

Comment: @Teemu ok , so is not better if i parse on my get ? here                                               getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
      entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
  } ??

Comment: That looks like another question. You can parse the data where ever you get it, though.

Comment: @Teemu well ty for help , 
I will try to look for parse, because with your example I understood how it works my I do not see how to apply it to my problem ^^